# Is there a procedure to make use of the hermiticity of a matrix to make matrix-vector multiplication faster?

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

Let, for example, B be a a 2X1 real vector and A be a hermitian 2X2 matrix, i.e. A=[a1, a2;a3, a4] where a1 and a4 are real numbers, and a3 and a2 are complex conjugate. Is there a way/procedure (preferably in python) to make use of the hermiticity of A to fasten the calculation of the matrix vector multiplication: A B

(Of course I want to apply such a procedure for matrix-vector multiplications of high dimensions. The simple example is just to clarify the idea)

Comment: What library are you using? NumPy? SciPy?  TensorFlow?  Each library probably has its own way of doing this

Comment: I'm working with numpy arrays but didn't find any function to do this procedure

Answer (score 0):

[image]
There are no common factors you could reuse (a_i b_j never occurs more than once), so I don't think you can speed this up.